# MBP Late 2016 Thunderbolt 3 issue: connected cables not recognized after sleep/wake up

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, thunderbolt

I have a new MacBook pro, late 2016 with Touch Bar, and recently bought some adapters (Aukey) to use my usb mouse, ethernet cable etc.

One thing that really bugs me is that the ethernet connection is lost whenever the computer wakes up. I have to unplug and re-plug it in again, i.e. the ethernet device is "unmounted" and does not get automatically detected again.

I didn't verify this behavior with my other equipment yet, but I guess this could be a general thing?

Anyway – is this a common error? Is there a cure?

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac on which you could test the ethernet adapter, just to double-check it's not a fault with the Aukey product?

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with the Monoprice Select Series USB-C to 3x USB-A 3.0, Gigabit Ethernet & USB-C Adapter. If I use the MacBook Pro 2016 w/ touchbar in clamshell mode with this adapter, the MBP will not wake from sleep at all. It's almost as if the adapter has gone to sleep, even though the lights on the ethernet port light up and blink and the AC adapter is plugged into the usb-c port on the adapter.

I have another ethernet adapter made by Anker that has 3 USB-A 3.0 ports on it that works just fine though. Might be a difference in chip set?